# Assign array values to contiguous intervals

Tags: numpy, optimization

I have a `levels` array

```
#                  0    1    2    3   4
levels = np.array(( 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 ))
```

and a `values` array, e.g.,

```
np.random.seed(20230204)
values = np.random.rand(5)
```

and eventually  a SLOW function

```
def map_into_levels(values, levels):
    result = []
    for n in np.asarray(values):
        for r, level in enumerate(levels):
            if n <= level:
                break
        else:
            r += 1
        result.append(r)
    return result
```

so that I have

```
In [153]: np.random.seed(20220204)
     ...: values = np.random.rand(6)
     ...: levels = np.array(( 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 ))
     ...: result = map_into_levels(values, levels)
     ...: print(levels)
     ...: print(values)
     ...: print(result)
[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8]
[0.00621839 0.23945242 0.87124946 0.56328486 0.5477085  0.88745812]
[0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4]

In [154]:
```

Could you please point me towards a Numpy primitive that helps me to speed up the operations?

Comment: I'm not particularly happy with my title… I encourage you to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) assuming `levels` is sorted already. It *find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order*:

```
np.searchsorted(levels, values)
# array([0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4], dtype=int32)
```